# pass url as a variable to window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a url from php and append an email field to redirect.

Here is what I have that doesn't work.

```
function redirect2() {
    var url = <?= $squrl2 ?> + document.form1.email;
    setTimeout('window.location.href = url.value;', 1000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: we are going to need a bit more than that. what's the value of squrl2, should probably be json_encoded so that javascript can parse it.

Comment: squrl2 varies and does not need to be parsed.
if it helps assume its http://ed-newman.com/test.php?email=

Answer (score 1):

You have many error in your code try following code

```
function redirect2(){
var url = "<?=$squrl2?>"+document.form1.email;
console.log(url);
setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = url;
}, 1000);
return true;
}
```

Be sure to get right url, I suggest first check value of url. Or share value of `$squrl2` and html element for email.

Comment: been using it without the function in the settimeout for years but changed it as you mentioned.
it has worked fine with a static url in settimeout.
this didn't work. goes to url but doesn't have email
where do I check console.log

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got to work.

```
function redirect2(){
   setTimeout(function(){
   location.href = "<?=$squrl2?>" + document.form1.email.value;
   }, 1000);
   return true;
}
```